# how do i specify connection parameters on the command line to run mysql in batch mode?

Tags: mysql

I need to be able to write a script to automatically connect mysql in batch mode so that I can run some .sql files.

I tried to enter the following at the prompt:

> ./mysql -u root -p mypassword

but I keep getting a "Enter password: " prompt.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of space.  Varies with shell.

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword dbname
```

It is likely interpreting "mypassword" as your dbname.

Comment: using mac osx terminal, I tried it still getting "Access denied for user..."

Comment: thanks, it was the space issue, but also my password had a character that interfered with the command, so I changed my password.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `--password=mypasswd`?

Comment: At least I answered your original question. Now you must have some trouble with your users right management. Check with your sysadmin the credentials you are using have the good right either on the local machine or on a remote one, depending on your env